# How can I do space-between vertically between rows

Tags: bootstrap-4

I want to achieve something like

```
[start-row]
  [space]
  [space]
  [space]
[end-row]
```

So it looks like this

[image]

I tried giving `align-self-start` and `align-self-end` but it does not give a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this

[image]

```css
body, html {
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="d-flex align-content-between border flex-wrap h-100 mb-3">
    <div class="p-2 w-100 border">row 1</div>  
    Some contents
    <div class="p-2 w-100 border">row 2</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want space between two column:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-dark mb-5">
      <p class="p-3 text-center text-light">Hello</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-dark mb-5">
      <p class="p-3 text-center text-light">I'm there</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want "space-in-the-middle" (between) to be auto-adjustable. Also I don't want to give container a height, otherwise I know an answer